# What .vimrc will be used if there are multiple?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm working on a centos7 machine.
In my home directory i have my .vimrc file

If i had a .vimrc file in the directory aswell, what one would Vim use and why?

Comment: `:h $MYVIMRC` "2 more to go..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any special configurations, `Vim` assumes that there is only a simple `.vimrc` file under `~/.vimrc`.

`Vim` is not going to search for another `.virmc`, in any other directory, unless you specifically instruct it to load another `.vimrc` from the `~/.vimrc` file

Answer (score 1):

Vim will use the `~/.vimrc` by default. If you wish to specify another initialization script, just do:

```
vim -u <PATH TO FILE>
```